# How to access a WCF REST Service inside .Net web application?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest, silverlight

I have a WCF web service which returns a JSON string from a Silverlight appication. I want to parse this JSON string inside a controller method in another web application. I cant create a service reference to the WCF service I created in Silverlight in the web application since it is a REST service. How can I access this WCF REST service in the other application?

Comment: @rene since it is a REST service i dont want to create a service reference

Comment: Sure, I only edited your post to get rid of the tag MVC. I added silverlight now because that better matches your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to access the web service with the following code

```
using System.Net;

public string GetWebServiceData()
    {
        try
        {
            string requestUrl = "requesturl";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            request.Expect = "application/json";
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return json;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(string.Empty);
        }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like the [System.Net.WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to call the WCF service in your controller.

There are a plethora of examples online on how to use it properly.

Personally, I use [JSON.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) or [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in all of my applications.